# deriving a table with combinations of keys from both the tables in oracle with one unique id and different dates

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I have two tables one is person and other one is his earnings

table structure for person

```
insert into  person (person_id,start_date) values (1,02-jan);
insert into  person (person_id,start_date) values (1,03-jan);
insert into  person (person_id,start_date) values (1,04-jan);
insert into  person (person_id,start_date) values (1,14-jan);
```

I have table called earnings and the structure is as follows

```
insert into  earnings (person_id,start_date) values (1,01-jan);
insert into  earnings (person_id,start_date) values (1,04-jan);
insert into  earnings (person_id,start_date) values (1,10-jan);
insert into  earnings (person_id,start_date) values (1,13-jan);
```

Here I have to derive a logic to a develop a table with has all the values from person and earnings joining 2 tables on person id and I need to have all the earning s data also.

here the start date of a person is the effective date from when the records get effective and same for earnings for that person.

the end table should be like this. I am sorry I cannot put a table structure in my questions so Im giving the insert statement.

desired table out put

```
insert into pers_earnings(person_id,person_start_date,earnings_start_date) values (1,02-jan,01-jan);

insert into pers_earnings(person_id,person_start_date,earnings_start_date) values (1,03-jan,01-jan);


insert into pers_earnings(person_id,person_start_date,earnings_start_date) values (1,04-jan,04-jan);


insert into pers_earnings(person_id,person_start_date,earnings_start_date) values (1,04-jan,10-jan);


insert into pers_earnings(person_id,person_start_date,earnings_start_date) values (1,04-jan,13-jan);


insert into pers_earnings(person_id,person_start_date,earnings_start_date) values (1,14-jan,13-jan);
```

let me know your suggestions to get this desired out put table.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace Table pers_earnings
as
Select 
person.person_id, 
person.start_date person_start_date, 
earnings.start_date earnings_start_date
from  person inner join earnings on person.person_id =  earnings.earnings_start_id
where
person_start_date <= earnings_start_date;
```